# Symfony - Form item as plain text

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a form that contains a collection of forms (a `Vote` with many `VoteChoice`). The `VoteChoiceType` is as follows

```
class VoteChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer', null, array('disabled' => true))
            ->add('priority', null);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PollBundle\Entity\VoteChoice',
        ));
    }
}
```

Now in my Controller I create and populate many `VoteChoices`, setting the `answer` according to the available choices for the current poll (derived from the URL)

```
$vote = new Vote();
$vote->setPoll($poll);
foreach ($vote->getPoll()->getPollOptions() as $op) {
    $vc = New VoteChoice();
    $vote->addVoteChoice($vc->setAnswer($op));
}
```

So when the Form loads, I want all the options to display only - not to be an actual choice, and then the user can set the priority they want. However, the answer is of every single answer I have in my `poll_options` table (each `Poll` has many `PollOption`, similar to how each `Vote` has many `VoteChoice`)

Current twig template

```
<ul class="voteChoices" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.voteChoices.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr')  }}">
    {% for voteChoice in form.voteChoices %}
            <li>{{ form_row(voteChoice.answer) }} {{ form_row(voteChoice.priority) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
<p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Go!</button></p>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I want the voteChoice.answer as a plain text (so it's not part of a dropdown - I know I can disable it in the FormBuilder, but I don't want it to appear as part of a drop-down menu, I just want it as plain text)

If I use voteChoice.answer I get the following symfony error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string") in poll\vote.html.twig at line 9.

I have a __toString function in my `VoteChoice` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the voteChoice.answer as a plain text (so it's not part of a dropdown - I know I can disable it in the FormBuilder, but I don't want it to appear as part of a drop-down menu, I just want it as plain text)

You can access the current data of your form via `form.vars.value` ([Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/rendering.html)):

```
{{ voteChoice.vars.value.answer }}
```

This means that `voteChoice.vars.value` is an instance of `PollBundle\Entity\VoteChoice` so you can remove the `answer` field from your form safely if this is not required by edit.

Comment: That's great, thank you! Exactly what I was trying to find. 

I'll leave the question open a bit longer to see if anyone can help me with my other issue, otherwise I'll mark your answer

Comment: Second half of question moved to new topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237645/symfony-why-does-my-form-get-every-answer-that-exists-in-the-table