# Symfony - Why does my form get every answer that exists in the table?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

This isn't so much an issue but rather something I noticed and would like to better understand.

I have a `Poll` class which has a collection of `votes` and `pollOptions`. 
My `PollOption` class has the `poll` it belongs to and a `title`.
The `Vote` class also has the `poll` it belongs to, as well as its own collection of `voteChoices` and `user`.
The `VoteChoice` class has the `vote` it belongs to, the `answer` (`PollOption`) that the vote is for, and a `priority`.

I have a form that contains a collection of forms (a `Vote` with many `VoteChoice`)

The `VoteChoiceType` is as follows

```
class VoteChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer', null, array('disabled' => true))
            ->add('priority', null);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PollBundle\Entity\VoteChoice',
        ));
    }
}
```

Now in my `VoteController` I create and populate a `Vote` with many `voteChoices`, setting the `answer` according to the available choices for the current poll (derived from the URL)

```
$vote = new Vote();
$vote->setPoll($poll);
foreach ($vote->getPoll()->getPollOptions() as $op) {
    $vc = New VoteChoice();
    $vote->addVoteChoice($vc->setAnswer($op));
}
```

So my twig is as follows

```
<ul class="voteChoices" data-prototype="{{form_widget(form.voteChoices.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr')  }}">
    {% for voteChoice in form.voteChoices %}
            <li>{{ voteChoice.vars.value.answer }} {{ form_row(voteChoice.priority) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
<p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Go!</button></p>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

However, if I enable `answer` in my `VotechoiceType` and in my twig include `{{ form_row(voteChoice.answer) }}` I notice that **all** my poll options from the table as in the selectable list, even if they are apart of another poll.

Why is this? How would I get it to just display options available form the poll the vote belongs to instead? My suspicion is I've not handled the relationship between the `VoteChoice` and `PollOption` correctly (many to one). If I've made a mistake here, I've likely done it elsewhere (eg a `Poll` might be getting every `Vote` in the db rather than the ones that belong to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$builder->add('answer', null, array('disabled' => true))
```

creates a ChoiceType-Field for `PollOption` and by default it populates it with all PollOption. There is nothing limiting the Choice-Field because your form doesn't know about the desired limitation given through `$voteChoice->getVote()->getPolloptions()`.

Take a look at Symfonys [EntityType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html): The `query_builder` option might give you a way to solve your issue, by adding a custom query to the answer-field, which selects to correct subset of PollOptions through the `VoteChoice -> Vote -> Polloptions` relation.

Comment: Ah, so I'm just basically just adding a `PollOption` that has yet to be set (so it can be any) as part of my builder, rather from the options derived from vote->getPoll()->getPollOptions()?

Comment: @p3tch yes, exactly. Symfonys FormBuilder just assumes you want a choice-field with all PollOption to choose from, as long as you don't specify what set you want in your dropdown