# BuildForm Symfony 2 - get Selected Value in ChoiceType

Tags: php, symfony, twig, formbuilder

How can I get the value of the item selected in my ChoiceType. I want to use it in a other form in my twig.
 This is my buildForm :

```js
$builder->add('number', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                '1'=>'Uns',
                '2'=>'Deux',
                '3'=>'Trois',
            ),
            'required'  => true
        ));
```

I want to do :

```js
{% if selectedValue == 1 %}
    //do something
{% endif%}
```

Edit : 
In my view , I have :

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.number) }}
        </div>
```

And if I selected a item , I have nothig :

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
         selected : {{  form.number.vars.value }}
        </div>
```

Edit 2 :
[image]

How i can get the selected value of my choiceType

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony - Form item as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227349/symfony-form-item-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the form attribute value with `vars` . As example:

```
{% if form.number.vars.value == 1 %}
    //do something
{% endif%}
```

Comment: Matteo > can you see my edit question please :) . I have nothing in the result